# AS3 XML object not throwing exception if invalid data is given?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, string, exception

I remember darkly that the XML class in AS3 would throw an exception if you tried to give it data in it's constructor that was not a valid XML string. But now I got a case where the XML happily takes every kind of data no matter it's valid XML or not...

```
var xml:XML;
try
{
    xml = new XML("Some bogus string content.");
    _valid = true;
}
catch (err:Error)
{
    _valid = false;
}
```

... am I missing something??

Update:
Qname somehow is null but somehow it's not, see here:

```
var qname:QName = xml.name();
if (!qname.localName)
{
    _valid = false;
}
```

... throws an exception. Obvioulsy qname is null! But ...

```
var qname:QName = xml.name();
if (!qname || !qname.localName)
{
    _valid = false;
}
```

... doesn't throw any exception. qname seems not to be null. WTH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example should give XML object with no name and with nodeKind equal to "text". This is how text nodes are represented in XML. In addition to try/catch, you may check for name().

Comment: Thanks! Trying to use xml.name() now to figure it out but QName is a rather unruly bugger, isn't it? (see my edit above)

Comment: Just cast it to string, it will be empty - "".

Comment: Ahhhh nevermind! figured it was some of my other implementation that caused QName being null. I checked it at the wrong time. Works properly now. :)

Answer (score 2):

The constructor of XML class converts input value to XML by using top level XML() function. And the top level XML() function converts a string to XML representation. It can convert other types of parameters. Check [XML constructor](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/XML.html#XML%28%29) and [top level XML() function](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/package.html#XML%28%29) manual for the details of what is converted to XML and what throws an exception.